# Image not clickable on popup in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, popupwindow

I have one popup which looks like as follow,

```
__________________
| Label 1      +<--this is  a plus img
|                |
| Label 2      + |
|________________|
```

I want to click that plus image, but when I am trying to do this getting one exception,

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <div class="popupActionsLabel">...</div> is not clickable at point (1012, 133). Other element would receive the click: <div class="popupActionsLabel">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.96)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-75-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 72 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'PC-3', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-75-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.5Z2sYt}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.96, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 2da36c1282dd134e5dec3c9024e86c48
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at com.trupublic.client.util.Thing.formShortcuts(Thing.java:240)
    at com.trupublic.client.restauranttapp.thing.MenuItemThingTest.testMenuItemThing(MenuItemThingTest.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I have implemented my code as follow,

```
    Webelement popup = driver.findElement(By.className("popupMainVPanel_CCPopupView"))

//This popup contains a list of web elements which I am taking as follow,

    List<Webelement> popupWebElementList = popup.findElements(By.className("actionLabelHPanel")); 

            String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            switchToPopup();  
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            for (WebElement element : popupWebElementList) {

                WebElement label1 = element.findElement(By.className("popupLabel"));
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                WebElement label1Img = element.findElement(By.className("popupImg"));
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                if (label1.getText().equals("Label1")
                        && label1Img.getAttribute("title").equals("Create Label1")) {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    label1Img.click();// at this line i am getting exception
                }
            }


public void switchToPopUp() {
        try {

            String subWindowHandler = null;

            Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
            Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window perform operations on popup
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception Occured in createActionForThing() ", e);
        }
    }
```

I am able to get all webelements even though getting this exception.

Comment: have you tried using Explicit wait for the same element before clicking the element?

Comment: yes I kept thread in sleep for 12000 miliseconds, even it's not working

Comment: What is the error that you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As element is not receiving the click so you need to first move to the element using actions class, and then click the element.

```
   Actions act = new Actions(driver);
           act.moveToElement(label1Img).build().perform();
   label1Img.click();
```

Comment: getting exception for StateElementReferenceException after implementing above code

Comment: label1mg; is it present on pop-up or parent window; if it is on parent window, then you need to switch back to parent window first as you've switched to pop-up

Comment: Label and plus image are on popup window, I am able to get all webelements of that popup, but clicking is not working on any of the webelement